dapr error: failed getting app id either from the URL path or the header dapr-app-id
I am using azure container apps and configured 3 apps to use dapr and service invocation. NGINX, API, and wbitt/network-multitool
In the NGINX I have this proxy set up and it works it invokes the service I have id'd at patient-api (API):
location /patient-api-uat/ {
 proxy_pass                      http://localhost:3500/;
 proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
 proxy_set_header                dapr-app-id patient-api;

}

this curl returns correct response:
curl https://pwsuat.domain.io/patient-api-uat/api/patient/1234567
when I log into the console of our network-multitool running in azure container apps also and I try this command:
curl -H 'dapr-app-id patient-api' http://localhost:3500/api/patient/1234567
I get this error:
{"errorCode":"ERR_DIRECT_INVOKE","message":"failed getting app id either from the URL path or the header dapr-app-id"}
Which doesn't make sense to me because I know dapr is up and running and working, and I'm passing the dapr-app-id header with the same id value.

check this link once- https://docs.dapr.io/developing-applications/building-blocks/service-invocation/howto-invoke-discover-services/
